# Flutter Authentication and Role checking

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am looking for a good solution to check in a Flutter Application if a user is authenticated and has a specific role. There are solutions where this is checked on a specific screen but is there also a more generic approach to check?

In Angular are guards available on Route, is there something similar in Flutter?
How do you handle such cases in Web-Application where you could enter any route directly?